# pandas drop 6 months interval before

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (with a "thing", a "date" and a "quantity" columns) in which I want to drop all occurrences of `quantity == 0` that are in a 6 months-period before every new occurrence of `quantity == 1`.

For this example,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
  {'id': 'thing 1', 'date': '2016-01-01', 'quantity': 0 },
  {'id': 'thing 1', 'date': '2016-08-01', 'quantity': 0 },
  {'id': 'thing 1', 'date': '2016-09-01', 'quantity': 1 },
  {'id': 'thing 1', 'date': '2016-10-01', 'quantity': 1 },
  {'id': 'thing 2', 'date': '2017-01-01', 'quantity': 1 },
  {'id': 'thing 2', 'date': '2017-03-01', 'quantity': 0 },
  {'id': 'thing 2', 'date': '2017-08-11', 'quantity': 0 },
  {'id': 'thing 2', 'date': '2017-09-01', 'quantity': 1 },
  {'id': 'thing 2', 'date': '2017-10-01', 'quantity': 0 },
])
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
print(df)
```

the expected output would be:

```
        id       date  quantity
0  thing 1 2016-01-01         0
2  thing 1 2016-09-01         1
3  thing 1 2016-10-01         1
4  thing 2 2017-01-01         1
5  thing 2 2017-03-01         0
8  thing 2 2017-10-01         1
```

My approach has been to group the df by "thing" and apply a mask based on dates:

```
print("Grouped df:")
grouped_df = df.groupby('id', as_index=False)

for key, item in grouped_df:
    print(grouped_df.get_group(key), "\n\n")

# my filtering function
def rem_interval(grp):
    idx = grp[grp['quantity'] == 1].index[0]
    return grp[(grp['date'] >= grp['date'][idx]) & (grp['date'] < grp['date'][idx]-pd.DateOffset(months=6))]

print("Filtered df:")
print(df.groupby('id', as_index=False).apply(rem_interval))
```

Two problems:

1. It does not work, as it returns an empty dataframe: serious problem.
2. It would not work in case of multiple intervals (as I take the first index of `quantity == 1`): potential problem. I could maybe cycle through the indexes and check the dates and concatenate portions of the groups, but I guess it is not the most efficient solution.

Does someone see a nice way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Code

```
g = df.loc[::-1, 'quantity'].cumsum()
dt = df.groupby(['id', g])['date'].transform('last') - pd.DateOffset(months=6)
mask = df['date'].gt(dt) & df['quantity'].eq(0)
```

#### Explanations

- Calculate the reverse cumulative sum on the `quatity` column in order to identify the groups of rows that ends with `1`.

```
>>> g

8    0
7    1
6    1
5    1
4    2
3    3
2    4
1    4
0    4
Name: quantity, dtype: int64
```

- Group the dataframe by `id` along with groups identified in the previous step, then `transform` the `date` column using `last` to get the date corresponding to the occurrence of `1` in each group

```
>>> df.groupby(['id', g])['date'].transform('last')

0   2016-09-01
1   2016-09-01
2   2016-09-01
3   2016-10-01
4   2017-01-01
5   2017-09-01
6   2017-09-01
7   2017-09-01
8   2017-10-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

- Now subtract an offset of six months

```
>>> df.groupby(['id', g])['date'].transform('last') - pd.DateOffset(months=6)

0   2016-03-01
1   2016-03-01
2   2016-03-01
3   2016-04-01
4   2016-07-01
5   2017-03-01
6   2017-03-01
7   2017-03-01
8   2017-04-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

- Create a boolean `mask` to identify the rows where the `date` corresponding to `0` occur within the last 6 months from the occurrence of `1`

```
>>> mask

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8     True
dtype: bool
```

#### Result

Filter the rows using the boolean `mask`

```
>>> df[~mask]

        id       date  quantity
0  thing 1 2016-01-01         0
2  thing 1 2016-09-01         1
3  thing 1 2016-10-01         1
4  thing 2 2017-01-01         1
5  thing 2 2017-03-01         0
7  thing 2 2017-09-01         1
```